# Bash: Numeric Argument Required

Tags: bash, shell

My code is as follows:

```
word=$1
if [ $word = "night" ]
then
    redshift -O 1300 > /dev/null
elif [ $word = "movie" ]
then
    redshift -x > /dev/null
else
    redshift -O 2800 > /dev/null
fi
```

Though every time I run it,

```
justin@justin: shift night
```

I get the error

> bash: shift: night: numeric argument required

When I run it as

```
./shift night
```

it works as expected.

I am not entirely sure why though.

(The idea is to write a script that changes the temperature of the screen based on a keyword and then build a GUI for it in Java to use it!)

Answer (score 6):

`shift` is the name of a built-in command in bash, explaining your weird error when you called it like that. In addition, even if you had called it something else, the current directory is not in your PATH, so you need to qualify a binary in the current directory with `./` to call it, as you discovered. (Had you called the command something else and not prefixed it with `./`, you would have gotten a command not found error.)

Comment: @justin, even if the script is in the PATH, the builtin takes precedence. You'll have to use `command shift night`. Best to give it a different name.

Answer (score 0):

[*Joseph Sible*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49594522/6136214) covers the question proper. Aside from that, the code should use `case` instead of all those `if`s:

```
case "$1" in
     night) redshift -O 1300 ;;
     movie) redshift -x ;;
     *)     redshift -O 2800 ;;
esac > /dev/null
```

Comment: It's a good enough suggestion, but it's not an answer to the question. At best, this is a comment on the question.

Comment: @chepner, Agreed.  Just a useful comment that wouldn't format as nicely in the current comment format.